# Type "myViewController" does not conform to protocol UIPIckerDataSource in Swift

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, uipickerviewcontroller, uipickerviewdatasource

I just create a new class in Swift, it's called `myViewController` and it's a `UIViewController`. 
Now I'm trying to make it a UIPickerViewDelegate and DataSource but *i got a strange error*

```
import UIKit

class myViewController: UIViewController, UIPickerViewDelegate, UIPickerViewDataSource {
   ...
}
```

It says `Type "myViewController" does not conform to protocol UIPIckerDataSource` over the UIPickerViewDataSource.

**Is it a bug of Xcode-Beta 3??**

[image: Screenshot for compile-time error]

Comment: 1) Please show how you implemented the required UIPickerViewDataSource methods. - 2) Why is there a typo in "UIPIckerDataSource"? Did you copy/paste the error message? - 3) The current version is Xcode 6 beta 4.

Answer (score 55, accepted):

You need to implement all the required methods of `UIPickerViewDataSource` and `UIPickerViewDelegate`, if you want to conform to these protocols.

**Swift is more like java when it comes to protocols** because if you don't implement all the required methods declared by a protocol you are going to get a compile time error instead of a run time exception.

Comment: Getting the same red warning for UIPickerViewDataSource. The UIPickerViewDelegate is fine. As soon as I add UIPickerViewDataSource I get the error. Strange.

Comment: I was facing the same exact error (running Xcode 6.1) To "fix it" (because it makes 0 sense why it now works), I simply removed the UIPickerViewDataSource protocol declaration. Then set self as the dataSource, then implemented the required 2 delegate methods. Finally re-added the protocol declaration. Now it works!

Comment: The "coolest" company in the world really needs to improve their half-coocked IDE...Too many bugs and weird errors for a company that "focus on excellency"

Comment: The second paragraph of your answer really saved my life! Thanks!

Answer (score 15):

Fix-it in XCode 8.1 inserts a deprecated version of the method below if you're using Swift 3:

```
func numberOfComponentsInPickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {
    return componentNumber
}
```

In XCode 10.0+

```
func numberOfComponents(in pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {
    return componentNumber
}
```

Answer (score 11):

Implement required method of `UIPickerDataSource` as in documentation.

> The data source provides the picker view with the number of
>   components, and the number of rows in each component, for displaying
>   the picker view data. **Both methods in this protocol are required.**

So you need to implement these methods

```
func numberOfComponentsInPickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView!) -> Int {}

   func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView!,
numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int{}
```

Answer (score 0):

My problem was that I had `override` in front of the implementation function, where Swift doesn't consider protocol method implementations to be overrides ([same](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24380681/swift-protocols-method-does-not-override-any-method-from-its-superclass)). Just taking out the `override` keyword fixed the issue.

Answer (score 0):

My problem is protocol's method name is illegal,

```
@protocol ContactsSelectDelegate <NSObject>

- (void)selectContacts:(NSMutableArray *)contacts Tags:(NSMutableArray *)tags;

@end
```

Here, `Tags:` should be `tags:`.
I hope my answer is helpful.