# Swift 1.2: Method does not override any method from its superclass

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

In my `SKScene` subclass I have implemented a `touchesBegan` method. This method had the `NSSet` changed to `Set` in order to make it Swift 1.2 compatible (see this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28771896/overriding-method-with-selector-touchesbeganwithevent-has-incompatible-type)).

```
override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<NSObject>, withEvent event: UIEvent) {
    // ...
}
```

Now the compiler gives me an error: **Method does not override any method from its superclass**. My code -as any Swift code- was broken in 1.2, and I have fixed every issue except this override case. Am I missing something here?

Comment: Duplicate of [Swift protocols: method does not override any method from its superclass](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24380681/swift-protocols-method-does-not-override-any-method-from-its-superclass) ? Does removing the "override" keyword help?

Comment: I need to use the override to know when a touch begins, right? So removing the override keyword makes the functionality fail. But yes, the project builds without overriding touchesBegan.

Comment: How is your `SKScene` subclass declared?  Something like `class MyScene: SKScene {` ?

Comment: `touchesBegan:withEvent` is a method in `UIGestureRecognizer`.  Are you defining your 'override' in a subclass of `UIGestureRecognizer`?

Comment: class MyScene: SKScene, OneAdDelegate { ..., that is the syntax I used

Comment: touchesBegan used to work in SKScene subclasses, and from what I've read it still should

Comment: @very_supercharged: Actually I don't get any error  message with your exact code in a SKScene subclass, but it fails to compile if the override keyword is removed. This makes sense because SKScene inherits from UIResponder. – Are you sure that you don't have any typo in the method declaration? Is the above a copy/paste of your actual code?

Comment: That's odd. I can compile without the override, but with it, an error occurs. The SKScene subclass is >700 lines long but the relevant parts -I assume- are posted here...

Comment: Maybe you have an 'embedded control character'.  Just recopy it from the UIResponder declaration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the "problem" had everything to do with the fact that the project had a Set class in it implemented, and I did not detect this redundancy. Quite a silly mistake.

Comment: Can you clarify your answer and show how you fixed it?

Comment: I had a custom "Set" class implemented in my project. To fix the problem, I just changed "Set" class to "ASet" class, so the compiler dealt with the correct Swift Set class.

Comment: Also as an FYI, for Swift 2.0 you want `override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?){}`

Answer (score 3):

This worked for me

```
override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
    //...
}
```

For more information about why is happening this error you can read from this answer that explain in detail about this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/30892467/2091181