# Override func error in Swift 2

Tags: swift, swift2

This code in XCode 6 does not have error but in XCode 7 (Swift 2) this error has occurred :

> Method does not override any method from its superclass

```
override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<NSObject>, withEvent event: UIEvent) {
        /* Called when a touch begins */

}
```

When remove `override` word this error occurred :

> Method 'touchesBegan(*:withEvent:)' with Objective-C selector 'touchesBegan:withEvent:' conflicts with method 'touchesBegan(*:withEvent:)' from superclass 'UIResponder' with the same Objective-C selector

Answer (score 77, accepted):

You're getting your first error because much of Cocoa Touch has been audited to support Objective-C generics, meaning elements of things like arrays and sets can now be typed. As a result of this, the signature of this method has changed and since what you've written no longer matches this, you're given an error explaining that you've marked a method as `override` but it doesn't actually match any methods from the super class.

Then when you remove the `override` keyword, the error you're getting is letting you know that you've made a method that has a conflicting Objective-C selector with the real touches began method (unlike Swift, Objective-C doesn't support method overloading).

The bottom line is, in Swift 2, your touches began override should look like this.

```
override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
    // stuff
}
```

For more information on what Objective-C generics mean for your Swift code, I suggest you take a look at the Lightweight Generics section in the prerelease version of [Using Swift with Cocoa and Objective-C](https://itun.es/us/utTW7.l). As of now on pages 33 & 34.

Answer (score 2):

Just delete the **override** it will works.

```
func touchesBegan(touches: Set<NSObject>, withEvent event: UIEvent) {
        /* Called when a touch begins */

}
```