# removing keyboard with swift

Tags: ios, swift, keyboard

I want to remove the keyboard after I am done with typing by clicking any where out of the box so I wrote this

```
 override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<NSObject>, withEvent event: UIEvent!) {
        self.view.endEditing(true)
    }
```

but it says that I am not overriding any method from the supper-class.But howcome ?:)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30892254/override-func-error-in-swift-2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For Swift 2, using:

```
override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?)
```