# Swift 2 upgrade Swift 3 compile error in many method such as willTransitionToTraitCollection:newCollection:withTransitionCoordinator

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, swift3

When I used swift 3 to run some old code, and convert them to newest swift 3. I found the method compile error

```
    override func willTransitionToTraitCollection( newCollection: UITraitCollection,
      withTransitionCoordinator coordinator: UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator) {
}
```

And compiler told me "Method does not override any method from its superclass"

should I import some modules?

Comment: remove `override` keyword ...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Swift protocols: method does not override any method from its superclass](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24380681/swift-protocols-method-does-not-override-any-method-from-its-superclass)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the Swift editor of my Xcode 8 beta 3:

```
class MyViewController: UIViewController {
    //Wait hear  ↓
    willTransition
}
```

I have got this suggestion:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    //Wait hear  ↓
    override func willTransition(to newCollection: UITraitCollection, with coordinator: UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator) {
        <#code#>
    }
}
```

(You need to remove all other syntax errors to get better suggestions.)

Anyway, you should not do everything by yourself. Make Swift do it.

---

New documentation for `willTransitionToTraitCollection:withTransitionCoordinator:` is here:

[willTransitionToTraitCollection:withTransitionCoordinator:](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uicontentcontainer/1621511-willtransitiontotraitcollection)

Comment: it's very kind of you ..swift 3  has changed many methods that confused me :(